# Power shell custom function in script

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, csv

I had prepared a script to pull some report w.r.t SQL server and out put will be pushed to different CSV sheets. After output is generated, all the CSV's are merged to single Excel file with the help of custom created function and that excel will be sent to my email address.

While running htrough powershell_ise.exe, it is running fine and I am receiving the email successfully. When I scheduled the same script, I am receiving the email but with out excel attachments. I am suspecting that custom created function is not used, because I dont see any converted excel files in the desired location.

I tried all possible ways, like dot sourching, pasting the function in the script itself but no luck.

I am a beginner in powershell, can some one please help me if i am missing some thing.

Thanks,
Anil

```
Function Merge-CSVFiles
{
Param(
$CSVPath = "D:\Anil\Missing_Indexes", ## Soruce CSV Folder
$XLOutput="D:\Anil\Missing_Indexes.xls" ## Output file name
)

$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem ("$CSVPath\*") -Include *.csv
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvFiles.Count
$workbooks = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$CSVSheet = 1

Foreach ($CSV in $Csvfiles)

{
$worksheets = $workbooks.worksheets
$CSVFullPath = $CSV.FullName
$SheetName = ($CSV.name -split "\.")[0]
$worksheet = $worksheets.Item($CSVSheet)
$worksheet.Name = $SheetName
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $CSVFullPath)
$CellRef = $worksheet.Range("A1")
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$CellRef)
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $True
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).Refresh()
$worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name).delete()
$worksheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$CSVSheet++

}

$workbooks.SaveAs($XLOutput,51)
$workbooks.Saved = $true
$workbooks.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbooks) | Out-Null
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

}
```

Comment: We're gonna need some more details about both the function that interacts with excel, and how you've configured the scheduled task (what account is it running as, what settings are on the task etc.)

Comment: Exactly what @MathiasR.Jessen said. However, I suspect your function is simply referenced before it is defined in the script. Ensure that your functions is defined in scope, before they are ever referenced.

Comment: @JacobColvin Not a bad guess, that's a classic powershell_ise pitfall ;-)

Comment: Thank you Jessen and Colvin for responding. Please see the below function I am using.

Comment: In addition, I configured the task with user who is having admin permissions. I cross verified and I assume nothing wrong with the settings of task coz it is generating the email and only thing it is missing is conversion of CSV's to Excel. I can post complete code if required.

Answer (score 0):

> While running through powershell_ise.exe, it is running fine and I am receiving the email successfully

This is because the ISE on your box is able to load your custom function during runtime and generate the report.

But when this is scheduled through a job, the script will run on a different server than your box, hence the script will not be able to find the function  and you don't get the report.

I have faced this kind of issue before while using custom functions.

The work around that i can suggest is wrapping for custom functions in a separate module and importing the module in your main script. ( preferably save the module in the same location as your script for easy troubleshooting).

Example:
Save your function in a .psm1 module file

```
Function ScriptExample {
Param ( [string] $script,
        [string] $jobname,
        [string] $jobcategory,
        [hashtable] $config,
        [string] $deletelogfilepath,
        [string] $servername)



#your-function-here#
 {
    }

Return $script;
```

}

Now call this module in your main script as follows,

```
$importmoduleroot = "C:\temp\SO_Example.psm1"

###### LOAD MODULES ######

# Import all related modules written to support this process
$modules = get-childitem -path $importmoduleroot -include SO*.psm1 -recurse;
```

You can then call your function and pass in the parameters within the main script,

```
ScriptExample -script $script `
            -jobname $jobname `
            -jobcategory $jobcategory `
            -config $config `
            -servername $ServerName `
            -deletelogfilepath $deletelogfilepath
```

Comment: @MK Can you please provide me steps in details for doing necessary changes or any example if you have .

Comment: Thank you for the steps MK. I created the custom function as a module and had called the same in my script. I was not able to completely understand the below example. Can you please explain the example in detail